# Pasting value only in those cells which meet criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a code where I will give input from the drop down that from which date we need to paste the data in row and next row suggest how many cells to the right of that i will go pasting the same data.

Lest assume I have a date drop down in cell `"E8"` and `"E9"` have what needs to copy and `"E10"` have how many times I have to paste the value from `"E9"` to the right. I have a date as a header from column `(J10:J40)`  please help

```
Worksheets("project Allocation").Range("E8").Copy

'PasteSpecial Values Only
  Worksheets("Project Allocation").Range("******").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Expected is for the selected dates pasting the values from cell `"E9"`

Comment: You can look at the `For Loop` .. Follow the link on how to use it (https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub CopyCell()
  Dim howManyTimes As Long, i As Long
  howManyTimes = Range("E10").Value
  For i = 1 To howManyTimes
    Range("E9").Offset(0, i).Value = Range("E9").Value
  Next
End Sub
```